# preg_match_all does not find occurrences of regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the following XML Dataset:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>10022389_0.141</DOCNO>
<TEXT>
      15-Hydroxyprostaglandin Dehydrogenase: Cinderella Meets Prince Serendip          John W. Funder  
</TEXT>
</DOC>


<DOC>
<DOCNO>10022389_144.85</DOCNO>
<TEXT>
    Baker Medical Research Institute  Melbourne, Victoria, Australia 8008   
</TEXT>
</DOC>


<DOC>
<DOCNO>10022389_232.223</DOCNO>
<TEXT>
     Address correspondence and requests for reprints to: John W. Funder, Baker Medical Research Institute, Monash University, P.O. Box 6492, St. Kilda Road Central, Melbourne, Victoria, Australia 8008.
</TEXT>
</DOC>

<DOC>
<DOCNO>10022391_0.162</DOCNO>
<TEXT>
      Treatment of Resistance to Thyroid Hormone&#151;Primum Non Nocere          Roy E. Weiss and   Samuel Refetoff  
</TEXT>
</DOC>



<DOC>
<DOCNO>10022391_250.510</DOCNO>
<TEXT>
     Address correspondence and requests for reprints to: Roy E. Weiss, M.D., PhD, Thyroid Study Unit MC 3090, Department of Medicine, University of Chicago, 5841 S. Maryland Ave, Chicago, IL 60637.  E-mail:  rweiss{at}medicine.bsd.uchicago.edurweiss@medicine.bsd.uchicago.edu.'//-->
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

I am using the following php code to find all the  tags in the above dataset

```
$data = file_get_contents($dataset);
preg_match_all("|<TEXT>(.*)</TEXT>|s",$data,$out);
```

The code above takes the first  occurrence and matches the LAST  occurrence and shows everything in between (which is the entire document excluding the first 2 lines and the last 2 lines for obvious reasons.

How can I make sure that `preg_match_all` find the occurrences in between?

I am fully aware of the fact that the dataset is NOT a valid XML file but I can not reformat it so please avoid leaving comments related to the XML.

Comment: You should use DOMDocument for this anyways, but `$out[1]` should contain each match.

Comment: @PHPglue thank you for the tip I will consider it, but lets stick to the code above because this isnt the first time this has happened to me so I would like to know why for future reference

Comment: @kingkero +1 thank you that did the trick, please leave it as an answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not really suited for parsing, in the long run you will be better off with using `DOMDocument`, as [PHPglue suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036347/preg-match-all-does-not-find-occurrences-of-regexp#comment44457375_28036347).

But for now: `.*` is greedy and will try to match as much as possible. So it makes sense to match everything between the first `<TEXT>` and the very last `</TEXT>`. If you do not want this behavior, use `.*?` instead.

Comment: another question related to this issue, When I try DOMDocument to parse the dataset it returns an error due to the dataset being invalid xml format. Is there a way to bypass this check or fix this error without modifying the dataset?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi I honestly don't know. However, if there isn't, there may be one in [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-basic.php) (which again, I can not guarantee, maybe it is easier to modify your code to valid XML than look for another method)